# Seeking Help to Correctly Identify Duplicated Number in an Array

Tags: python, arrays

I'm working on a problem where I need to find a duplicated number in an array. The array contains sequential values from 1 to N(20000,40000,60000,80000,100000), with one number repeated. My goal is to identify and return that duplicated number.

I've implemented three algorithms to tackle this problem:

Exhaustive Solution: This approach involves using two nested loops to compare every pair of elements in the array, looking for a duplicate.

Improved Solution 1 (with sorting): In this method, I first sort the array and then check adjacent elements for duplicates.

Improved Solution 2 (without sorting): This approach is based on the fact that the array contains all numbers from 1 to N. It compares the sum of the elements in the array with the expected sum if there were no duplicates. The difference between these sums should reveal the duplicated number.

The issue I'm facing is related to the "Improved Solution 2" and the find_difference_between_sums function. It's not correctly identifying the duplicated number, and I'm seeking assistance to fix this problem. My objective is to make sure that the function find_difference_between_sums accurately identifies the duplicated number based on the difference between the sum of elements and the expected sum.

```
import time
import random

def array_fatorial_add(nums):
    result = 1
    for elemento in nums:
        result += elemento
    return result

def create_array_with_duplicate(N):
    nums = list(range(1, N + 1))
    duplicate_index = random.randint(0, N - 1)
    nums[duplicate_index] = 5
    random.shuffle(nums)
    return nums

def measure_time(func, nums):
    start_time = time.perf_counter()
    result = func(nums)
    end_time = time.perf_counter()
    return result, end_time - start_time

def find_difference_between_sums(nums, N):

    actual_sum = array_fatorial_add(nums)

    expected_sum = (N * (N + 1)) / 2

    difference = expected_sum - actual_sum
    return difference
array_sizes = [20000, 40000, 60000, 80000, 100000]

for N in array_sizes:
    nums = create_array_with_duplicate(N)
    difference, time_taken = measure_time(lambda x: find_difference_between_sums(x, N), nums)
    print(f"Solução Melhorada 2 (sem ordenamento): Diferença = {difference}, Tempo = {time_taken:.6f} segundos")

    print()
```

On def create_array_with_duplicate I used 5 as the duplicated number so I could understand better what was happening. The timer is still with some errors but i'll fix it.

Comment: Why not use  `sum(nums)` instead of `array_factorial_add(nums)`?

Comment: @The_spider I did that too but it keeps giving me wrong numbers I cant understand why

Comment: There are no arrays in this code, just lists.

Answer (score 0):

In your problem, you initialise `result` in the sum with `1`, but you should initialise it with `0`.

The final duplicated number should also be `actual_sum - expected_sum`. You have it the wrong way round for a duplicated number. (Your way round would be the case for a missing number.)

And your created array doesn’t have one extra number: you’ve just replaced a perfectly good one.

It's sad but there is a quick trick to this problem, based on the fact that the xor operation on the same number twice produces 0. Thus, if you do it on the unduplicated numbers and then array with one number unpaired-off, then you will be left with that single unpaired number.

```
def duplicateNumber( A ):
   ans = 0
   for i in range( 1, len( A ) ): ans ^= i;   # numbers from 1 to unduplicated length
   for i in A: ans ^= i                       # numbers with one duplicate
   return ans                                 # this one is unpaired off
print( duplicateNumber( [ 3, 2, 5, 2, 4, 1 ] ) )
```

Output:

```
2
```

Comment: The thing is that I want need to do this problem based on the improved Solution 2 (without sorting) that the array contains all numbers from 1 to N. It compares the sum of the elements in the array with the expected sum if there were no duplicates. The difference between these sums should reveal the duplicated number.

Comment: Yes, that’s what my post starts with:  you incorrectly started from result=1 rather than result=0 when summing your actual array. Then you have the difference of sums the wrong way round.

Comment: Oh, and your created array is wrong in the first place, because you are replacing one number rather than duplicating it. Just append your extra digit, not replace a good one.

Comment: Our comments crossed - check your array creation.

Comment: YOU ARE A LEGEND (sorry for the caps but had to be done) thank you so much I was doing this for hours, can you tell me where I did wrong?

Comment: My edited post starts with the three things that I think you did wrong. But a better approach to debugging would be to start with a small array and simply output the array and the relevant sums. Any problems would reveal themselves here.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting here is a waste of time.
If you have the memory just use a set to keep track.

```py
seen = set()
for e in my_list:
    if e in seen:
        return e
    seen.add(e)
```

If you want to sort first or have a sorted sequential list, just keep checking the middle number. If the number is lower than its position  you know your repeated number is to the left of it. This is like a binary search.

```
sorted_list = list(range(10000))

sorted_list.insert(3333,3333)

left, right = 0, len(sorted_list) - 1

while left <= right:
    print(left,right)
    mid = (left + right) // 2
    expected_mid = sorted_list[0] + mid

    if sorted_list[mid] == expected_mid: left = mid + 1
    else: right = mid - 1
    

print(sorted_list[left])
```

Comment: I'm sorry I do thank you for the work but this is a university problem so right now I don't need other solutions I just need to understand why is my solution not working... thanks anyways!

Comment: fine fine, but notice that summing the whole list to find out the difference to the expected sum is a poor solution. Going through the list and summing every element has basically the same cost as checking every element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [].index and build a list of duplicated

```
l=[random.randint(0,100) for i in range(50)]
dup=[] # (value, index, replicated_index)
for i,j in enumerate(l):
    try: 
        k = l.index(j,i+1)
        dup.append((j,i,k))
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

Or build dict with values as keys and list if duplicated indices as values

```
l=[random.randint(0,100) for i in range(50)]
dup={} # value: [index1, index2, ...]
for i,j in enumerate(l):
    try: 
        k = l.index(j,i+1)
        dup[j].append(k) if j in dup else dup.setdefault(j,[i,k])
    except ValueError:
        pass
```